# Static Library vs. Source Code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, open-source, static-libraries

I'm creating a modular open-source library. Let's say the project has 15 `.m` files in it.

Should I (1) release it like the [Venmo iOS SDK](https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk) (Cocoa Touch Static Library) or (2) release it like [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) (just the source code)?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want people to be able to modify it once they download it.

Comment: "Should you"? How are *we* supposed to know? We don't know your requirements better than you do! If someone is pointing a gun at you and says to use X, then yes, you should use X.

Comment: Searching around also pointed me to this: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

Comment: I suggest, if you do not release it as source code, to do it as a framework or both a framework and a static library.

Answer (score 1):

Releasing as source code means you, and your developers, don't have problems when a new architecture comes out. A static library built as armv6 wouldn't work with the latest Xcode today.

One caveat with source code releases, since you don't know what build settings the project it's added to will have, you'll need to do extra work to make sure it builds without warnings as best you can, even for pedantic warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer frameworks over static libs.  Its easier to ship resources in the framework bundle if you eventually need to and there no cost to dynamic linking.  If its pure C and the libraries dependencies are guaranteed to be there then it might be ok.  But in general I try to avoid static linking unless I know the target OS has the exact dependencies for that binary at deployment time.

Its much easier to load a dynamic library with the endpoints you need at runtime (which were compiled for that exact platform but have the same external interface) than it is to fail with a static lib that was compiled directly to external dependencies which dont exist on the target platform.

Maybe Im crazy but this is what Ive always done in C, C++ or obj C.  Just my opinion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library

Comment: I'm not sure but I think iOS doesn't support frameworks with dynamic libraries.

Comment: When you link to a framework in an iOS project my assumption is thats a dynamic link - I could be wrong. But i dont think so, since my projects copy the framework bundles into their locations...which are loaded sat runtime.  If I were to statically link them I wouldnt need those bundles at all, the code would be part of my executable.

Comment: Any and all sources I can find on the web mention iOS frameworks have to be static. It's possible the system frameworks can get around this restriction.

Comment: Admittedly I have been doing mostly OSX development with frameworks, I havent done custom ones for iOS so...My mileage may vary.

Comment: @stackmonster, millimoose is completely correct. iOS libraries can only have static linkage for security reasons. The only exceptions are the dynamic link libraries that are shipped from Apple with the iOS SDK.

Comment: My point was more that with frameworks you have acces to resources i the bundle besides linking to code and even if the code is linked statically, those bundles are shipped with your app afaik which is not strictly speaking static linking